# How to declare a function template that accepts forwarding reference and returns either a reference or a copy

Tags: c++, c++14, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to declare a function template that should accept and return a non-const reference when passed an lvalue, but return an RVO-compatible local copy when passed an rvalue:

```
<template ?>
? StringReplace(? str, ? from, ? to);
```

I want template to generate the following signatures:

1. for non-const lvalues

   ```
   std::string& StringReplace(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to);
   ```
2. for const lvalues

   ```
   std::string StringReplace(const std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to);
   ```
3. for non-const rvalues

   ```
   std::string StringReplace(std::string&&, const std::string&, const std::string&)
   ```
4. for const rvalues

   ```
   std::string StringReplace(const std::string&&, const std::string&, const std::string&)
   ```
5. for string literal

   ```
   std::string StringReplace(std::string&&, const std::string&, const std::string&)
   ```

---

Is it possible to specify one using single template?
Perhaps there is a function or method in the standard library that achieves the same result by using one or multiple templates I should use as a reference?

---

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49346191/188530) for the version I ended up with.

Comment: Forwarding references are *based on* template argument type deduction. If you explicitly specify the type, it stops being a forwarding reference. There is no way to make the explicitly specified version behave differently based on the parameter since there is no deduction going on.

Comment: Do you mean [2] (and only [2]) will not be generated?

Comment: @Kentzo: I mean that #2, #4, and #5 cannot *all* be true of the same function.

Comment: Also, how do you plan to use the object you're given? Your function is called `StringReplace`; are you doing a modification of the value you're given? If so, how do you deal with being given a `const&`?

Comment: Move-construct from the const reference.

Comment: 2 and 4 seem useless.

Comment: The line `return std::forward<Str>(str);` implies that you must have worked in-place on `str` (which is a reference parameter). This function can't cope with a const lvalue argument (and nor did you specify in your question that it should)

Comment: @Kentzo: You cannot move from a `const` reference because... it's *`const`*.

Comment: @NicolBolas well, you can do `T t = std::move(x);` which will work even if `x` were declared as const reference. It falls back to copy for non-movable types

Comment: @NicolBolas You're right, meant copy-construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this basic idea meets your requirements:

```
template<typename Str>
Str foo(Str&& str)
{
    return std::forward<Str>(str);
}
```

If the argument is a non-const lvalue, then `Str` is deducted to `S&` and the forward resolves to `S&` also.

If the argument is an rvalue then `Str` is deduced to `S`, and the return value is copy/move-constructed from the argument.

If you explicitly give the template argument, then forwarding reference deduction is suppressed and you would have to make sure to give `S&` if the function argument is an lvalue that `S&` can bind directly to; or `S` otherwise.

There is never RVO for a function parameter passed by reference;  e.g. suppose the calling context were `std::string s = StringReplace( std::string("foo"), x, Y);` , the compiler cannot know at this point to use the same memory space for `s` as the temporary string.  The best you can do is to move-construct the return value.

---

*Note:* Your original code tries to deduce `Str` for all 3 arguments, this causes deduction conflicts. You should deduce the forwarding reference and for the other two, either use a non-deduced context or a different template parameter.  For example:

```
template<typename Str, typename T>
Str StringReplace(Str&& str, T const& from, T const& to)
```

or use the `CRef` as shown in super's answer (deduction is disabled if the parameter appears to the left of `::`).

Comment: I.e. if I want RVO I need to declare 2 templates: one that accepts by value and another that accepts by reference?

Comment: @Kentzo Well if you accept by value then you've made a copy/move at the point of initializing the function parameter. So, even if you do NRVO for that parameter, it would not be any more optimal than the original code

Comment: Doesn't this just fail deduction if you pass in an lvalue together with 2 rvalues? [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4lWiMj79PZADVCu0)

Comment: @super `""` is an lvalue. If you want to support this argument set you need to disable deduction for the 2nd and 3rd arguments, or use another type

Comment: @M.M So how is your example supposed to be used then? I can't find any way to call it with an `lvalue` as the first parameter without getting deduction failure.

Comment: What is the purpose of `std::forward<Str>` in return, isn't it redundant?

Comment: @Kentzo `std::forward<Str>(str)` translates to `std::move(str)` if and only if the argument was an rvalue

Comment: I understand. Isn't it redundant in that context?

Comment: @Kentzo If you don't use it, then the parameter will be copied instead of moved into the return value; I'm assuming you would prefer to move when possible

Answer (score 2):

With some aggressive molding of parameters and return value, this seems to do almost what you specified.

Case 2 need to be specified with `<std::string&>` or the forwarding reference will not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using CRef = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type const&;

template<typename Str>
Str StringReplace(Str&& str, CRef<Str> from, CRef<Str> to)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

    if (std::is_same<std::string&&, decltype(str)>::value)
        std::cout << "rvalue-ref\n\n";
    else if (std::is_same<std::string&, decltype(str)>::value)
        std::cout << "lvalue-ref\n\n";

    return std::forward<Str>(str);
}

int main() {
    std::string s1;

    StringReplace(s1, "", "");

    // Forwarding reference will deduce Str to std::string& when passing an lvalue
    StringReplace<std::string&>(s1, "", "");

    StringReplace(std::move(s1), "", "");

    StringReplace<std::string>(std::move(s1), "", "");

    StringReplace<std::string>("", "", "");

    const std::string& test = s1;
    StringReplace(test, "", "");
}
```

A question mark remains for how to deal with `const &` being passed in. As you can see if you run this, it will also return a `const &` as it stands now.

[Live example](https://ideone.com/tfSfT1)

Comment: Yeah, good point. I thought forwarding reference would deduce to `std::string&&` but I see now from reading the documentation that it deduces to `std::string` for rvalues.

Comment: Is it required to define `CRef` outside of the template or I could use `const std::remove_reference_t<Str>&>` directly inside the template?

Comment: Defining it outside was only to improve readability. You can use it directly inside the template as you suggest.

Comment: The issue with the current solution is that it allows const lvalue reference. It will cause a compilation error as substring replacement requires calling non-const functions.

Comment: @Kentzo You can add a static_assert to give a compile time error if you try to pass a const ref. Or you can use SFINAE to pick a different overload that returns a copy in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the commentaries and answers I ended up with two templates:

```
// true only if T is const
template<typename T>
using StringReplaceIsConst = std::conditional_t<std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value, std::true_type, std::false_type>;


// lvalue, lvalue reference, rvalue, rvalue reference, string literal
template<typename Str, typename = std::enable_if_t<!StringReplaceIsConst<Str>::value>>
Str StringReplace(
    Str&& str,
    const std::remove_reference_t<Str>& from,
    const std::remove_reference_t<Str>& to
) {
    return std::forward<Str>(str);
}

// const lvalue, const lvalue reference, const rvalue, const rvalue reference
template<typename Str, typename = std::enable_if_t<StringReplaceIsConst<Str>::value>>
std::decay_t<Str> StringReplace(
    Str&& str,
    const std::remove_reference_t<Str>& from,
    const std::remove_reference_t<Str>& to
) {
    std::decay_t<Str> mutableStr{std::forward<Str>(str)};
    StringReplace(mutableStr, from, to);
    return mutableStr;
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/d2Tpkf)

---

While the version above works I find it impractical. The user is actually interested in whether modification is done **in place** or **in a copy**:

- Simpler debugging: user can add logging to verify which version is called
- Static analysis: user can annotate the definition to make compiler automatically issue warnings

With these points in mind:

```
// true only if T is a non-const lvalue reference
template<typename T>
using StringReplaceIsInPlace = std::conditional_t<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value && !std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value, std::true_type, std::false_type>;

// lvalue, lvalue reference, rvalue reference, 
template<typename Str, typename = std::enable_if_t<StringReplaceIsInPlace<Str>::value>>
Str StringReplace(
    Str&& str,
    const std::remove_reference_t<Str>& from,
    const std::remove_reference_t<Str>& to
) {
    return std::forward<Str>(str); // forward might be redundant, as Str is always an lvalue reference.
}

// const lvalue, const lvalue reference, rvalue, const rvalue, const rvalue reference, string literal
// std::decay ensures that return is by-value and compiler can use RVO
template<typename Str, typename = std::enable_if_t<!StringReplaceIsInPlace<Str>::value>>
std::decay_t<Str> StringReplace(
    Str&& str,
    const std::remove_reference_t<Str>& from,
    const std::remove_reference_t<Str>& to
) {
    std::decay_t<Str> mutableStr{std::forward<Str>(str)}; // move construct for non-const rvalues, otherwise copy-construct
    StringReplace(mutableStr, from, to);
    return mutableStr; // RVO-compatible
}
```

The second declaration can be annotated with `[[nodiscard]]` (C++17), `[[gnu::warn_unused_result]]` (clang and gcc) or `_Check_return_` (msvs).

[Live example](https://ideone.com/TulRXJ)