# perfect forwarding function deduced conflicting error

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

I am testing perfect forwarding, and I dont understand why `TEST_EQ(string("olleH"), s)` compile failed, but `string("olleH") == s` compile pass. How do I fix my `TEST_EQ` function here?

```
template<typename S>
static bool TEST_EQ(S&& a, S&& b) 
{
    return forward<S>(a) == forward<S>(b);      
}


int main()
{
 string s= "Hello";

 cout << TEST_EQ(string("olleH"), s) << endl;
 cout << (string("olleH") == s);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the deduction rule of [forwarding reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), when you try to call `TEST_EQ` as `TEST_EQ(string("olleH"), s)`, for the argument `string("olleH")`, which is an rvalue, then `S` will be deduced as `std::string`; for the argument `s`, which is an lvalue, then `S` will be deduced as `std::string&`. The deduction result is conflicting then the calling fails.

You can add another template parameter to avoid such deduction conflicting, e.g.

```
template<typename S, typename T>
static bool TEST_EQ(S&& a, T&& b) 
{
    // if you need to check that S and T should be the same type
    static_assert(is_same_v<remove_cvref_t<S>, remove_cvref_t<T>>, "S and T must be the same type.");

    return forward<S>(a) == forward<T>(b);      
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dDi4bV8tBcHJJSQ8)

Comment: I won't suggest that fix because OP's intention is to test perfect forwarding. I would suggest `template <typename S, typename T> static bool TEST_EQ(S&& a, T&& b)` instead.

Comment: Another way would be to disable deduction for the second parameter ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331851/1505939)) for the basic idea)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so just find out that I cant pass two different value type by one template argument. So this compile, maybe add a static_assert to check A, and B type would be a good solution.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
static bool TEST_EQ(A&& a, B&& b) 
{
    return (forward<A>(a) == forward<B>(b));      
}
```